# Intel J1900+Ubuntu 16.04——Occured OS hang-up and freezing

Tags: 14.04

Intel J1900+Ubuntu 16.04 occured OS hang-up and freezing randomly. We tried to ajust some BIOS setting as belowed,but it seems that doesn't work.

```
1、advanced -> cpu configuration -> Power Technology：custom
2、advanced -> cpu configuration -> CPU C6 report：disable
3、advanced -> cpu configuration -> CPU C7 report：disable
4、advanced -> cpu configuration -> EIST：disable
5、advanced -> ppm configuration -> CPU C state Report：disable
6、advanced -> ppm configuration -> Max CPU C-state：C1
7、chipset-> north bridge -> Intel IGD Configuration -> IGD Turbo Enable：disable
8、chipset-> north bridge -> Intel IGD Configuration -> DVMT Pre-Allocated：128M
9、chipset-> north bridge -> Intel IGD Configuration -> DVMT Total Gfx Mem：MAX
10、chipset-> north bridge -> Graphics Power Management Control -> RC6(Render Standby)：disable
```

I heard that this issue has occured before. Can you tell me whether this issue has been solved or not? Or can you give me some other advices?
I am looking forward to your reply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, those Baytrail problems might have been fixed in newer kernels - 4.11+. Check your kernel version with `uname -r`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question: this issue can be only fiexd by upgrading the kernel?

Comment: I don't know of any other way. Fortunatly, Ubuntu makes it very easy to get kernels upgrdes with its [HES](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Answer (score 0):

forget any kernel, the problem is the mobo. You only need to change the c state to C1 on the bios.Then you'll never  have any problem with any kernel.